# MS Access Creating IFERROR to remove #Error across my queries

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, error-handling

I have a series of inspections occurring in a city infrastructure workflow and currently if an inspection is missing, that shows up as errors because it did not join. Because of a tree of rules, if any inspections are missing, the whole things gets rounded up into an error.

I need a way to assume a result if there is an error

Just looking for a functioning IIF(iferror(variant),1,0) custom vba but it seems to just skip VBA when there is an error regardless.

This is the statement, and Nz() doesn't work because there is no data that might be null, just no match at all.

```sql
SELECT
   IIf([PavingStatus]=1,CorrectedPavingofInitial.RAF,
   IIf([PavingStatus]=0,CorrectedForm_3.RAF,0)) AS RAF
FROM
   CorrectedPavingofInitial RIGHT JOIN (
     CorrectedForm_3 RIGHT JOIN [Work] ON CorrectedForm_3. 
     [PavingData.RampID]=Work.RampID) ON 
     CorrectedPavingofInitial.RampID = Work.RampID
```

```vb
Public Function ErrorText(InputText As String)

If Iserror(InputText) Then
  ErrorText = 0
  Exit Function
endif

ErrorText = 1

End Function
```

But it gives #Error where there were errors and 0 everywhere else

Comment: You don't tell where _that shows up as errors_, but check the recordset's record count; if zero, don't proceed.